Balancing players into two teams
I'm trying to find an algorithm which would arrange ranked players into 2 teams automatically before the game starts in a balanced way.
The game has 2 teams, each team can have up to 5 players, and each player has a skill rating, the higher the rating the greater the skill of the player in the game. Player rating ranges from 900 to 2100.
Example:

player1 - rating: 1400
player2 - rating: 1450
player3 - rating: 1500
player4 - rating: 1550
player5 - rating: 1600
player6 - rating: 1650
player7 - rating: 1700
player8 - rating: 1750
player9 - rating: 1800
player10 - rating: 1850

How to arrange these players into 2 teams so that the team average rating between teams is as balanced as possible ie. the difference between 2 teams average rating is the smallest?

Is the number of players always the sum of the team sizes? (The example may be too simple. Imagine two selectors: after an initial choice of one player, they alternatingly select two, or a last one to complete the team. Can you find an example where this greedy procedure does not work?)

With 10 players, just try all possible arrangements.

With more players, this is a variant of the partition problem.  You can adapt the standard dynamic programming algorithm for the partition problem, to solve this problem as well.
Specifically, we'll let $A[t,k,j]$ be true if there is a subset of $k$ of the first $j$ players whose total rating is $t$, or false otherwise.  Notice that you can fill in the entries of the array $A$ using the following recurrence relation:
$$A[t,k,j] := A[t,k,j-1] \lor A[t-r_j,k-1,j-1],$$
where $r_j$ denotes the rank of the $j$th player.
Then, once you have filled in all of the entries of $A[\cdot,\cdot,\cdot]$, it is easy to find the optimal solution by iterating over all $t,k$ such that $A[t,k,n]$ is true (where $n$ denotes the total number of players), computing $|t/k - (T-t)/(n-k)|$ (where $T=\sum_i r_i$ denotes the sum of all players' ratings), and remembering the one where this difference is minimized.
The total running time will be $O(Tn^2)$, where $n$ is the number of players and $T$ is the sum of their ratings.  For realistic problem sizes, this should be efficient.

It is a separate question whether, in practice, the average rating is the best predictor of a team's success.

For some reason i thought there are more combinations, but for arranging 10 players in 2 teams there are only $\binom{10}{5}=252$ so trying all possible arrangements will work fine. Thanks for your answer, including for more players that looks interesting.
